# Can crictl check ports?

Tags: docker, containers

`docker ps` lists the following fields

```sh
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND      CREATED     STATUS     PORTS       NAMES
```

I'm interested in the `PORTS` field and I'm using crictl `crictl ps` does not show me the exposed ports. Any idea how can I check this ? I also check the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/ and still I could not find it. Am I missing something ?

I know that crictl is not a general purpose workflow tool, as I am using for debugging purposes.

Comment: You could try to `crictl inspect` the containers and see if the information you're looking for is there, but if you're running under kubernetes I don't think you're going to find anything -- I believe kubernetes is using a different mechanism for exposing ports (e.g., services, load balancers, etc) so you won't find published ports in the pod metadata.

Comment: thx it seems so, what helped me to investigate was to `oc debug node/NODE_NAME`  and `oc adm node-logs --role=master -u crio`